# compiler error: control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have this code and the compiler gives me the next error:

> functions.c:12:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function 
>        [-Wreturn-type]
>   }

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int myrand(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand()%2;

}
```

This function is invoked from another .c file here:

```
printf("%d here \n", myrand());
```

Comment: `int myrand(){ ... }` is a function that returns an `int`. The compiler is expecting a `return` statement, like `return r;` perhaps

Comment: The function should return an `int` value.

Comment: Congratulations.  Did you have a question to go along with those disclosures?

Answer (score 0):

Add a return statement.

```
int myrand(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand()%2;
    return r;
}
```

Without it, the "random" value you print doesn't come from `rand()`, but from the undefined behavior that is omitting the return statement. [Well, technically, depending on architecture, the return value of `rand` can be propagated in a register]

While the [c](/questions/tagged/c) standard may allow omitting it without demanding a hard error, this is still ill-advised.

Comment: Thank you very much, just saw this error by myself)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error after much research and reading through manuals, turns out control reaches end of non-void function.

```
int myrand(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand()%2;
    return r; // add this
}
```